# How to use cy.session() as a replacement for Cypress.Cookies.defaults() to store a unique Id

Tags: cypress

Currently I am using `Cypress.Cookies.defaults({ preserve: 'uniqueId' });` in my Cypress tests to persist a unique Id across multiple tests. However, I recently updated Cypress to version 12.9.0 and discovered that `Cypress.Cookies.defaults()`  was deprecated in version 12.0.0 and replaced with cy.session().

How can I persist a single unique Id using cy.session()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `cy.session()` in a `beforeEach()` hook. Any cookies set there will be preserved across tests.

The setup function of cy.session() is responsible for setting the cookie original value.

Setup is only called once, subsequent calls to cy.session() restore the cookie from cache.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('cookies', () => {
    cy.setCookie('session_id', '189jd09sufh33aaiidhf99d09')
  })
})

it('Test1', () => {
  cy.getCookie('session_id')
    .should('have.property', 'value', '189jd09sufh33aaiidhf99d09')
})

it('Test2', () => {
  cy.getCookie('session_id')
    .should('have.property', 'value', '189jd09sufh33aaiidhf99d09')
})
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. `Cypress.Cookies.defaults()` and `cy.setCookie()` have completely different signatures, one taking a list of cookies to preserve and the other a name value pair.

Comment: Is there a point you are trying make?

Comment: Sorry, but I agree with Andreas - this has some interesting pointers but it's not answering the question. Before, `Cypress.Cookies.defaults()` would cache a cookie, but the solution here is setting a cookie to a constant - it's not caching what's being set by the app under test.